# Unable to understand PoW Algorithm?

Tags: contract-development, proof-of-work

As per my current understanding PoW algorithm is to ensure that only the decided number of blocks are made in a time frame and we adjust difficulty accordingly.
I'm a beginner in Solidity and Ethereum and i want to understand each line of this code, please help me to analyze it

```
bytes32 public currentChallenge;                         // The coin starts with a challenge
uint public timeOfLastProof;                             // Variable to keep track of when rewards were given
```

Line 1: currentChallenge is a variable of type byte32 ( sequence of 32 bytes, 256 bits in total )

Line 2:uint is a datatype for currency amount and dates ( in unix time )

```
  uint public difficulty = 10**32;                         // Difficulty starts reasonably low
```

Line 3: What does 10**32 does ? I have an idea that it is related to number of bits but not crystal clear about what it does

```
    function proofOfWork(uint nonce){
    bytes8 n = bytes8(sha3(nonce, currentChallenge));    // Generate a random hash based on input
    if (n < bytes8(difficulty)) throw;                   // Check if it's under the difficulty
```

Line 4: proofOfWork accepts nonce ( any random number ) as input, which I'll be manually entering in my Ethereum Wallet.

Line 5: We create a random hash by concatenating nonce and currentChallenge and store it in n

Line 6: If the computation by current nonce is not able to match the difficulty then do not proceed

```
        uint timeSinceLastProof = (now - timeOfLastProof);  // Calculate time since last reward was given
    if (timeSinceLastProof <  5 seconds) throw;         // Rewards cannot be given too quickly
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += timeSinceLastProof / 60 seconds;  // The reward to the winner grows by the minute
```

Line 7 and Line 8 : Can we compare time just by adding unit(seconds) just like in Line 8:, how does it work ?

```
difficulty = difficulty * 10 minutes / timeSinceLastProof + 1;  // Adjusts the difficulty
```

Line 9: This is based on unitary method, if blocks are being made in more than 10 minutes then lower the difficulty , else increase it. Again same doubt as in Line 3 what's happening on multiplying ( * ) , why are we adding 1 ?

```
    timeOfLastProof = now;                              // Reset the counter
    currentChallenge = sha3(nonce, currentChallenge, block.blockhash(block.number-1));  // Save a hash that will be used as the next proof
```

Line 10 and Line 11 : Update timeOfLastProof and currentChallenge.
Getting inside the parameter 3 in sha3
block.blockhash(block.number-1), I have asked this in another thread too , and i got to know that:

1. blockhash(block.number-1) gives blockhash ( a random number) of the previous block, and we are taking the previous block specifically to maintain the chain. Is this right ?
2. block.blockhash(block.number-1) - Is there a structure with the name block and blockhash one of its data members ?

Comment: Line 2. 10**32 is 10 to the power of 32, commonly written as 10^32, or 100000000000000000000000000000000 (32 zeroes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose of any *Proof of ...* system is to pick a random node to confirm that nobody cheated in the last block(s). And it does so in a *decentralized* way, i.e. no central random generator.

> Line 3: What does 10**32 does ?

It is 10 to the power of 32. Your hashcode must be lesser than this number to win the lottery and be the miner of the block.

> Line 7 and Line 8 : Can we compare time just by adding unit(seconds) just like in Line 8:, how does it work ?

They are just constants, see it as multiplications: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?

`10 * minutes` is only a way to say `10 * 60` so 10 minutes in seconds

> Line 9: This is based on unitary method, if blocks are being made in more than 10 minutes then lower the difficulty , else increase it. Again same doubt as in Line 3 what's happening on multiplying ( * ) , why are we adding 1 ?

`timeSinceLastProof` then guarantees that the more time passes the smaller the difficulty. +1 to ensure no division by zero is possible

> block.blockhash(block.number-1) - Is there a structure with the name block and blockhash one of its data members ?

Correct:
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=blockhash#block-and-transaction-properties

> blockhash(block.number-1) gives blockhash ( a random number) of the previous block, and we are taking the previous block specifically to maintain the chain. Is this right ?

No this is because current block number is the actual block and does not have a hash yet, it is not mined... so you have to take the last one.

Comment: added further response

Comment: Thanks a lot, your input is really helpful.
One more thing in the first line of function where we are creating a random hash, any reason for using bytes8 ?

Comment: Good question can't see why ATM, maybe you make a question out of it?